# How to find the number of solutions in $2\cot 4x=3-3\cot 2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> Find the number of solutions from the equation from below in the given
> range.
>
> $2\cot 4x=3-3\cot 2x$
>
> Assume $x\in \left[0,\frac{3\pi}{4}\right]$

I am not sure what to do here. All what I was able to do was to find the values of the cotangent function as follows:

For brevity purposes I'm posting the simplification which I arrived after algebraic manipulation:

$4\cot^2 2x -3\cot 2x -1 =0$

Then this gets me to:

$(4\cot 2x+1)(\cot 2x-1)=0$

which means:

$\cot 2x=-\frac{1}{4}$

and

$\cot 2x = 1$

But now what?. This is exactly where I'm stuck. It would help me a lot if someone could **gently guide me** on what should be done next to find the number of solutions in the required interval.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 2\cot 4x-3+3\cot 2x$. Observe that $f'(x) <0$. Now find discontinuities of $f(x)$ to happen at multiples of $\frac{\pi}4$. Hence, there only $3$ roots in $[0,3\pi/4]$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$\tan2x=-4\implies2x=n\pi+\arctan(-4)=n\pi-\arctan4$$

Now $\arctan4>\arctan\sqrt3=\dfrac\pi3$

$$\tan2x=1=\tan\dfrac\pi4\implies 2x=?$$